# I want to change reference of css in html files

Tags: html, css, reference

i want to change my reference of css file from local server to a CDN and i have got so many pages ,rather then changing them one by one i want to change them all together ,i am using visual studio 2010.

Comment: Use Find and replace option to do it. Ctrl +Shift +F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly there is a function in Visual Studio to replace the same code in your entire project.

Try Ctrl + Shift + H.